# empty EditText caused by wrong view?

Tags: android, sqlite, view, android-edittext

I'm new to android studio and programming. I create second table to my database and have almost identical onClickListener class first one work perfect but second give me error. EditText .getText().toString() is empty so I can't convert it to dobule. I think this problem may be caused by View but I dont know java that well and I cant find solution.

EDIT: I manage to solve this problem by adding AlertDialog to my second OnClick listener. This is not exactly what I want but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try setting the input type on the edittext as numberDecimal

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

That way, the user will have to input decimal number always if thats what you are expecting the user to enter.
Also, you could do a null check

```
if(stringWzrost != null && !stringWzrost.trim().equals("")) { 
    bmiWzrost = Double.valueOf(stringWzrost);
}
```

Right now I see that its commented out.

Comment: I have android:inputType="numberDecimal" in my xml. I comment IF because when I dont do it there is no error but nothing is added to my database. Edittext is empty and I cant figure out why.